# Linq Table select where IN IQueryable

Tags: linq, entity-framework-core

I have two classes; the first one is:

```
public class People
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public Dog Dogs {get;set;}
}

public class Dog
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public int PeopleId {get;set;}
    public bool IsNewborn {get;set;}
}
```

PeopleId of Dog class is the Id of People class.

Now, with Entity Framework, I retrive the list of Newborn Dogs:

```
var AllNB_dogs = _dog_repository.Table;
AllNB_dogs = AllNB_dogs.Where(x => x.IsNewborn );
```

What I need to retrive now, is the list of People that have newborn dogs.

I try with:

```
var PeopleWithNB = _people_repository.Table.Where(x => AllNB_dogs.Contains(x.Id));
```

but I know that in "Contains" I cannot put an Int but I need to insert a People object.

I try also with:

```
var PeopleWithNB = _people_repository.Table.Select(x => ...);
```

but without success.
Can someone help me? Or there is another way to accomplish this?

I'm using EF Core 2.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a relation between `People` and `Dogs`, so that you can use [`Any`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any):

```
var PeopleWithNB = _people_repository.Table.Where(x => x.Dogs.Any(d => d.IsNewborn)).ToList();
```

See [Relationships in Entity-Framework Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key)

Answer (score 0):

According to your design every human has exactly one Dog, there are no People without dogs (I'm sure there are a lot of people without dogs), nor people with more than one Dog. I wonder what you would do if someone sells his Dog.

Furthermore, People have a property `Dogs`, it seems that you wanted to design a one-to-many relationship between People and Dogs. Every Human has zero or more Dogs, every Dog belongs to exactly one Human, namely the Human with PeopleId.

If you really wanted a one-to-one relationship (every Human has exactly one Dog), see below. I'll first handle the one-to-many relation.

### One To Many

People have zero or more Dogs, every Dog belongs to exactly one Human, namely the Dog that PeopleId refers to.

Usually tables are identified with plural nouns, rows in tables are identified with singular nouns. Because the word People has some problems when explaining, I'll change it to something more standard. For your final solution the identifiers that you select are not important. Most important is that everybody immediately understands what you mean.

Rewriting your classes:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    ... // other Customer properties

   // every Customer has zero or more Dogs (one-to-many)
   public virtual ICollection<Dog> Dogs {get;set;}
}

public class Dog
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public bool IsNewborn {get;set;}
    ... // Other Dog properties

    // Every Dog is owned by exactly one Customer, the Customer that OwnerId refers to
    public int OwnerId {get;set;}
    public virtual Customer Owner {get; set;}
}
```

> In Entity framework, the columns of the tables are represented by the non-virtual properties, the virtual properties represent the relations between the tables (one-to-many, one-to-one, many-to-many, ...)

Note that a foreign key is an actual column in your table, hence it is a non-virtual property.

The -to-many part is best represented by a `Collection<...>`, not by a `IList<...>`. The reason for this is that all functionality of a Collection is supported by Entity Framework: Add / Remove / Count. An IList has functionality that is not supported by entity framework, better not offer it then, don't you agree?

For completeness the DbContext:

```
class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Customer> Customers {get; set; }
    public DbSet<Dog> Dogs {get; set;}
}
```

Most people directly access the DbContext. It seems you have a repository class. Alas you forgot to mention this class. Anyway, you have functions like:

```
IQueryable<Customer> Customers = ... // query all Customers
IQueryable<Dog> Dogs = ...           // query all Dogs
```

** Back to your question **

Ok, so you have a query to fetch the sequence of several Dogs (in this case: all new born Dogs) and you want the list of Customers that own these Dogs.

If you use entity framework with proper virtual relations, this is quite easy:

```
// Get all owners of New Born Dogs:
var result = dogs.Where(dog => dog.IsNewBorn)
                 .Select(dog => new
{
    // Select only the Dog properties that you plan to use:
    Id = dog.Id,
    Name = dog.Name,
    ...

    Owner = new
    {
        // Select only the properties that you plan to use:
        Id = dog.Owner.Id,
        Name = dog.Owner.Name,
        ...
    }),
});
```

In words: from the sequence of Dogs, keep only the newborn dogs. From every remaining Dog, select properties Id, Name. From the Owner of this Dog, select properties Id and Name.

You see: by using proper plural and singular nouns, and by using the virtual relations, the query seems to be very natural.

The problem with this is that, if Customer[4] has two new born dogs, you get this Customer twice. It would be better to query:

Give me all Customers with their newborn Dogs.

Whenever you have a one-to-many relationship, like Customers with their Dogs, Schools with their Students, Orders with their Products, so whenever you want items with their sub-items, it is best to start at the one side (Customers) and use a GroupJoin.

```
var customersWithTheirNewbornDogs = customers.Select(customer => new
{
    // Select only the Customer properties that you plan to use
    Id = customer.Id,
    ...

    NewbornDogs = customer.Dogs.Where(dog => dog.IsNewborn)
                               .Select(dog => new
                               {
                                    Id = dog.Id,
                                    ...

                                    // not needed, you already know the value:
                                    // OwnerId = dog.OwnerId,
                               })
                               .ToList(),
})
// Result: all Customers, each with their newborn Dogs,
// even if the Customer has no newborn Dogs.

// if you only want Customers that have newborn Dogs:
.Where(customer => customer.NewbornDogs.Any());
```

In words: from every Customer take some properties, and from all Dogs that he owns, keep only the newborn ones. From the remaining ones, take some properties. Finally, keep only Customers that have at least one newborn Dog.

** but I'm using entity framework CORE! **

I've heard from some people who can't use the virtual properties when using EF-core. In that case, you'll have to join the tables yourself:

Starting on the many side: **GroupJoin:**

```
// GroupJoin Customers and newbornDogs
var customersWithTheirNewbornDogs = customers
.GroupJoin(dogs.Select(dog => dog.IsNewborn), 
customer => customer.Id,                 // from every Customer take the Id
dog => dog.OwnerId,                      // from every Dog take the foreign key
(customer, dogsOfThisCustomer) => new    // when they match, take the customer and his Dogs
{                                        // to make one new object
    Id = customer.Id,
    ...

    NewBornDogs = dogsOfThisCustomer.Select(dog => new
    {
         Id = dog.Id,
         ...
    });
});
```

Or if you want to start on the many side: **Join**

```
var newbornDogsWithTheirOwners = dogs.Where(dog => dog.IsNewborn)
.Join(customers,
dog => dog.OwnerId,                   // from every Dog take the OwnerId,
customer => customer.Id,              // from every Customer take the Id,
(dog, owner) => new                   // when they match, take the dog and the owner
{                                     // to make one new
     Id = dog.Id,
     ...

     Owner = new
     {
          Id = owner.Id,
          ...
     }
});
```

### One-to-One

If in your world every People has exactly one Dog, there are no People without Dogs, and no one has several Dogs, than you can do the Join similar as above.
(by the way, see how strange it sounds if you don't use proper plurals and singular nouns?)

```
var newbornDogsWithTheirOwners = dogs.Where(dog => dog.IsNewborn)
.Join(People,
dog => dog.PeopleId,            // from every Dog take the foreign key,
customer => customer.Id,        // from every Customer take the Id,
(dog, owner) => new             // when they match, take the dog and the owner
{                               // to make one new
     Id = dog.Id,
     ...

     Owner = new
     {
          Id = owner.Id,
          ...
     }
});
```